# PostgreSQL10 OLAP using row

Tags: sql, postgresql, olap

Why it's wrong with 'rows 2 following' ,but right with 'rows 2 preceding' and 'rows between 2 preceding and 2 following' ?
And,how I can correct 'rows 2 following' ?
Thank you for help

[image]

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and include the queries in the question *as text*.

Comment: `between current row and 2 following`

Answer (score 0):

When you are using window frames, always include both ends of the frame.

The frame `rows 2 following` is ambiguous.  Do you mean `rows between current row and 2 following` or `rows between 2 following and unbounded following`?  Each of these has problems.

The first is not allowed, because frame starts must appear before frame ends:

> Restrictions are that frame_start cannot be UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING,
>   frame_end cannot be UNBOUNDED PRECEDING, and the frame_end choice
>   cannot appear earlier in the above list than the frame_start choice.

Also, when only one time specification for the frame is included, it is included as the frame start.

So, Postgres interprets `2 following` as the start of the frame.  But, the default for the end is the current row, so it is interpreted as `rows between 2 following and current row`. Hence the error message that it produces:

> 42P20: frame starting from following row cannot end with current row